# request for member 'resize' in 'abs', which is non-class type 'char**'

Tags: c++

i have this code, and the compiler says in this line

```
abs.resize(jlh);
```

request for member 'resize' in 'abs', which is non-class type 'char**'.

edit:i need abs and mhs to be in char so i can encrypt in the next step.

what do i have to do? thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    int jlh,x,y;

    char **mhs=new char*[100];
    char **abs=new char*[100];

    cout<<"enter students total: ";
    cin>>jlh;


    abs.resize(jlh);
    for(x=0;x<jlh;x++){
        cout<<"enter students name: ";
        mhs[x] = new char[1024000];
        cin>>mhs[x];
        cout<<"enter students presensi: ";
        cin>>abs[x];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays can't be resized. Consider using a `std::vector<std::string>` Did you really mean to allocate a megabyte for a name? Since it appears you have data to group together you might wrap both the name and presensi in a struct or class and use a single vector of that.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::vector`, your problem will be fixed - you won't even have it to begin with. Arrays are not classes, they don't have methods.

Comment: do i only put it on the top of my code? @RetiredNinja

Comment: do i only put it on the top of my code?  @Mat

Comment: `abs` is a pointer to a pointer.  As such, it does not have any member functions to call.  `abs.resize(jlh)` attempts to call a member function.

Comment: @Mat -   There are actually no arrays in the shown code either - there are pointers that are initialised to point at dynamically allocated memory.   A pointer is not an array, even if it behaves like one in some contexts.

Comment: @Peter I would call `mhs` an array of pointers. Is that incorrect terminology?

Comment: If `mhs` is an array of pointers, what would `char *foo[100]` be?    They are not the same type, so they can't *both* be an array of pointers.    Even if they can both be used as if they are in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> abs(100);
    ...
    abs.resize(jlh);
    ...
}
```

For full details consult a [book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You really need one if you are going to learn C++. You cannot learn C++ by guess work.

Comment: can't i make abs into char? bcs i need it to be in char so i can encrypt the text i collect:"D

Comment: @pluto98 You can create a `const char *` from a string with `abs[x].c_str()`.